# .htaccess deny from all, redirect to 404 page and except for 2 files

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

How do I setup a .htaccess that denys any `.php` file access in the `include/` folder, and redirect user to `error` page in the `public_html/` (root) directory when 403, 404 and 500 occurs, but except for 2 files that are called `index.php` and `key.php`?

Currently this is what I have:

```
<Files "^*\.php$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html

<FilesMatch "^(index|key)\.php$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

but this does not work properly, only `<FilesMatch "^(index|key)\.php$">` works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want something reachable, then it should be within your document root to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You should place your `.htaccess` file into the `include/` directory, if it's not the case.
I think you used the `FilesMatch` syntax for a `Files` tag.

```
<FilesMatch "^.*\.php$>
    order deny,allow # Deny here, allow later.
    deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "^(index|key)\.php$">
    allow from all  # Allow here.
</Files>
```

Then, in your root (`public_html/`), you can use :

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
# Try ../error.html if you put this line in include/.htaccess
```

Make sure the path to `error.html` is valid. If you see something like "*an error was encountered looking for the error document*", then it's wrong (try absolute path from the Linux root ?)